# array function wrong output

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I want square root of elements of array but the output is so wrong !!!
 can you help to correct my error???
how can i change array to size 100?

```
 #include <math.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    // function declaration:
    double sqrootx(int arr[], int size);

    int main ()
    {
       // an int array with 5 elements.
       double balance[5] = {1000, 2, 3, 17, 50};
       double sqr;

       // pass pointer to the array as an argument.
       sqr= pow( balance, 5 ) ;

       // output the returned value 
       cout << " result" << sqr << endl; 

       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your code really doesn't make any sense. We also have no idea what you're trying to do or what output you expect. For example, is the function `sqrootx` supposed to replace each entry in the array with its square root? If so, why does it return a single `double`?

Comment: I wonder what should be output of an array's power...?

Comment: you have to put each and every element in pow() not the whole array pointer

Comment: Is this guy your classmate by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802594/array-function-c

Comment: How do you expect us to diagnose the failure of `sqrootx` if you haven't shown us the function's code?

Answer (score 2):

In order to create an array of size 100. Simply Change the 
`double balance[5];` to 
`double balance[100];`

This being said, its very hard to enter 100 numbers, manually.
Therefore you need to run a LOOP.

Judging from the code given, lets list things that are missing in your code.

1. A **loop** that fills each box in your array with a number.
2. The pow function itself. (since you have declared math.h , use **sqrt**)
3. Another loop(iteration) or Recursion to replace the original number in the array with the square rooted value.
4. A loop or a function to **display** the array that has all the value square rooted.
5. Some predefined conditions such as "negative values" or some bit of code to **absolute** them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo:

```
sqr= sqrootx( balance, 5 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are raising your numbers to the power of 5. Square root is power of .5.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    sqr = pow(balance[i], .5);
    cout << " result" << sqr << endl;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be a cleaner way to just call sqrt